# How do I add a "Background & Context" section to symbol doc pages in Workbench?

Tags: documentation, workbench

Some of the documentation pages for *Mathematica* 10's built-in symbols have an additional "Background & Context" section (just below the Details section) that's reserved for textbook-type information.  See for example: [`Pi`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pi.html?q=Pi), [`Sin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin.html?q=Sin), [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html?q=Part), etc...

[image]

I would like to add this section to some of the symbol pages for my packages.  How can I add a new section (that is closed by default) to symbol pages within Wolfram Workbench?

Additional question: will adding this section cause any problems when trying to load these pages from older version of *Mathematica* like 8 and 9?

Answer (score 2):

I do not have WB with me now, but I think that the different sections in the documentation pages are basically all the same, in the sense that you can simply add a new section (using a "section" button) and then simply change the heading. Another good way (probably the best) to really emulate official doc pages, is to use ctrl-shift-E and see the cell code in the official pages and then just copy/paste and edit the code in your doc pages.

Comment: I tried that: "section" button actually creates a section of the type you see  *within* the More Examples section.  It doesn't create a whole section all together.

Comment: For reference, @QuantumDot: what version of Workbench do you have?

Comment: @J.M. I have workbench 2.0 build 138 for Mac OS X

Comment: The sad truth is that version 2 has not been updated in years. My impression is that WRI is not too interested in having users  producing professionally looking packages with documentation, ect.